# Is it proper to pluralize when amount is unknown?

Tags: grammatical-number, appropriate

The rules I know:

> 0 count of item : "zero item**s** *plural*
>
> 1 count of item : "one item" *singular*
>
> greater than 1 count of item : "many item**s**" *plural*
>
> less than 0 count of item (as in mathematics) : "negative one item / negative *x* item**s**"

This leads me to believe that it's proper to use plural form in any situation where the count is not exactly 1.

- Jonny has (unknown amount of) apple - (to me this is wrong)
- Jonny has (unknown amount of) apple**s** - (to me this is correct)

If Jonny has (unknown amount of) apple**s**, is it then acceptable to say:

> Jonny has apples - (I think so, and there are many examples of this in English; however it occurs to me that Jonny may have 0 apple**s** and therefore you wouldn't say 'Jonny has apple**s**' but rather 'Jonny has no apple**s**' or 'Jonny does not have any apple**s**')

Is there any situation in where this is not the case? For example if:

> I know that Jonny has 0 apple**s** and I give him 1 apple.
>   `Jonny now has 1 apple.`
>
> But if I don't know how many apple**s** Jonny has and I give him 1 apple.

Would I still say that `Jonny has 1 (an) apple`? or is it acceptable to say `Jonny has apples` because I don't actually know for certain how many apple**s** Jonny has?

Comment: If you know Jonny has at least 1 apple because you gave him one, you could say "Jonny has one or more apples," or "Jonny has one apple for sure, possibly more." Or something along those lines.

Comment: @developerwjk so I guess what you're saying is that there isn't a concise way of stating the 1 or more aspect ?